# Update specific Values using Firebase for Android

Tags: android, firebase

I have a Firebase data created as follows

```
tasks
-K1NRz9l5PU_0R8ltgXz
   Description: "test1"
   Status: "PENDING"
 -K1NRz9l5PU_0CFDtgXz
   Description: "test2"
   Status: "PENDING"
```

I need to update the 2nd object's status from PENDING to COMPLETED. I am using the `updateChildren` method but it is added a new node to the tasks child.

How do I update the status of the 2nd node without creating a new node?

Here is my code as of now,

//on a button click listener

```
  {

    Firebase m_objFireBaseRef = new Firebase(AppConstants.FIREBASE_URL);        
    final Firebase objRef = m_objFireBaseRef.child("tasks");    
    Map<String,Object> taskMap = new HashMap<String,Object>();
    taskMap.put("Status", "COMPLETED");
    objRef.updateChildren(taskMap); //should I use setValue()...?

 });
```

Answer (score 37):

You're not specifying the task id of the task that you want to update.

```
String taskId = "-K1NRz9l5PU_0CFDtgXz";

Firebase m_objFireBaseRef = new Firebase(AppConstants.FIREBASE_URL);        
Firebase objRef = m_objFireBaseRef.child("tasks");
Firebase taskRef = objRef.child(taskId);
Map<String,Object> taskMap = new HashMap<String,Object>();
taskMap.put("Status", "COMPLETED");
taskRef.updateChildren(taskMap);
```

Alternatively, you can just call `setValue()` on the property you want to update

```
String taskId = "-K1NRz9l5PU_0CFDtgXz";

Firebase m_objFireBaseRef = new Firebase(AppConstants.FIREBASE_URL);        
Firebase objRef = m_objFireBaseRef.child("tasks");
Firebase taskRef = objRef.child(taskId);
Firebase statusRef = taskRef.child("Status");
statusRef.setValue("COMPLETED");
```

Or:

```
Firebase m_objFireBaseRef = new Firebase(AppConstants.FIREBASE_URL);        
Firebase objRef = m_objFireBaseRef.child("tasks");
objRef.child(taskId).child("Status").setValue("COMPLETED");
```

### Update

Not sure what "I need to track the ID based on the status" means. But if you want to synchronize all tasks that are in status `Pending`, you'd do:

```
Firebase m_objFireBaseRef = new Firebase(AppConstants.FIREBASE_URL);        
Firebase objRef = m_objFireBaseRef.child("tasks");
Query pendingTasks = objRef.orderByChild("Status").equalTo("PENDING");
pendingTasks.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot tasksSnapshot) {
        for (DataSnapshot snapshot: tasksSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            snapshot.getRef().child("Status").setValue("COMPLETED");
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {
        System.out.println("The read failed: " + firebaseError.getMessage());
    }
});
```

Comment: how to get the taskId dynamically? is there a getKey method available?

Comment: There is indeed a `getKey()` method. But you haven't specified based on what criteria you want to update the task. Usually if the user of your app changes the status in a screen somewhere, you'll track the id of that task.

Comment: yes i need to track the ID based on the status. If the status is completed then i need to update the task. Any idea how to do that? also how do I limit the number of "PENDING" records to be fetched. I tried using limitToFirst(10) but it fetches more than 10 tasks

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen  I think  your update part not update the  2nd object's status from PENDING to COMPLETED. but , it update all objects  with status pending.  am I right?

Comment: Correct. The first snippet changes the status of one specific task. The second snippet changes the status of all pending tasks.

Answer (score 7):

You can use code below to update

```
HashMap<String, Object> result = new HashMap<>();
        result.put("Description", "Your Description comes here");

FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("tasks").child("-K1NRz9l5PU_0R8ltgXz").updateChildren(result);
```

It will update a specific child

Answer (score 6):

This code will find the node content `test2`, then update the Status. Hope this help. I am using Google Firebase.

```
FirebaseDatabase firebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    final DatabaseReference reference = firebaseDatabase.getReference();
    Query query = reference.child("tasks").orderByChild("Description").equalTo("test2");
    query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            DataSnapshot nodeDataSnapshot = dataSnapshot.getChildren().iterator().next();
            String key = nodeDataSnapshot.getKey(); // this key is `K1NRz9l5PU_0CFDtgXz`
            String path = "/" + dataSnapshot.getKey() + "/" + key;
            HashMap<String, Object> result = new HashMap<>();
            result.put("Status", "COMPLETED");
            reference.child(path).updateChildren(result);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            Logger.error(TAG, ">>> Error:" + "find onCancelled:" + databaseError);

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

You guyz are not helping ...we are trying to know what function can help us get the key so that the updates can be automatically without comparing any value . Am on the quest if there is a path i will let u know PERTH

```
Log.e(TAG, "Key2 is "+getRef(position).getKey());
```

*Please usefirebase Ui Seems the original firebase doesnt have yet.*

Answer (score 0):

You Just need to get the right key Value from the push Method then Update the children when your task is completed by addOnCompleteListener

```
MyTaskModel myTaskModel = new MyTaskModel();
myTaskModel.Description = "My Text Is Here";
myTaskModel.Status = "PENDING";
        final FirebaseDatabase mFirebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        final DatabaseReference databaseReference = mFirebaseDatabase.getReference().child("tasks");
        final DatabaseReference dbr= databaseReference.push();
        final String key = dbr.getKey();
        Task task1 = dbr.setValue(myTaskModel);
        task1.addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {

                                     Map<String, Object> taskMap = new HashMap<String, Object>();
                                     taskMap.put("Status", "COMPLETED");                  
                                     FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("tasks").child(key).updateChildren(taskMap);

                                    }
                                }
                            );
```

Answer (score 0):

```
     val taskRef = databaseReference.child("crop_cycle_tasks")
        val matchingCropCycleTask = taskRef.orderByChild("taskName").equalTo(task?.taskName)
        matchingCropCycleTask.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(object : ValueEventListener {
            override fun onDataChange(tasksSnapshot: DataSnapshot) {
                for (snapshot in tasksSnapshot.children) {
                    snapshot.ref.child("taskStatus").setValue(updatedStatus)
                    Timber.d("Mapped ${task?.taskStatus} status to $updatedStatus status for ${task?.taskName}${task?.selectedCrop} F1 CYCLE" )
                }
            }
            override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError) {
                Timber.v("Failed to update status {}", error.message)
            }
        })
```