# How to modify an specific value in Firebase?

Tags: android, firebase, reference, firebase-realtime-database

I have this data in Firebase Database:

```
Negocios:
  -KjfCu56lFZCybYldBZy
       lugarReference: "Restaurante"
       numeroMesas:39
       password:"pass123"
       user:"user123"
       user_id:"usr_1"
```

I have two applications connected to one project in Firebase, one of them upload data of restaurants reservation, and the other one displays reservations in a RecyclerView.

In the first application, once I do a reservation, it must minus one to `numeroMesas` value, the other application should display any changes to this key.

In the reservation application, I have this piece of code that I did base in this question:

[Update specific keys using Firebase for Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33315353/update-specific-keys-using-firebase-for-android)

It supposes to modify the value of `numeroMesas`, but it does not:

```
 mReference.child("Negocios").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {

                   @Override
                    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                        for(DataSnapshot postSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                            Lugar lugar = postSnapshot.getValue(Lugar.class);
                            if(nombre_lugar.equals(lugar.getUser_id())){

                                DatabaseReference numMesasReference = mReference.child(dataSnapshot.getKey()).child("numeroMesas");
                                numMesasReference.setValue(lugar.getNumeroMesas() - 1);
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                    }
                });
```

What it does is the next thing:

```
Negocios:
      -KjfCu56lFZCybYldBZy
           lugarReference: "Restaurante"
           numeroMesas:39
           password:"pass123"
           user:"user123"
           user_id:"usr_1"
      -Negocios
          -KjfCu56lFZCybYldBZy
               numeroMesas:39
```

How can be fixed? 
I need to minus one once I do a reservation... 
Greetings!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `postSnapshot.getRef()` you obtain a reference to the source location for this snapshot. So what's next is to add a child to that reference, that reference will be "numeroMesas" that is the key you want to modify.

As easy as that, the code will be like this.

```
mReference.child("Negocios").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
          @Override
               public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    for(DataSnapshot postSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                        Lugar lugar = postSnapshot.getValue(Lugar.class);
                        if(nombre_lugar.equals(lugar.getUser_id())){

                              DatabaseReference numMesasReference = postSnapshot.getRef().child("numeroMesas");
                              numMesasReference.setValue(lugar.getNumeroMesas() - 1);

                                }
                            }
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                        }
                    });
```

**P.S:** If you want to minus one just once by reservation, `addValueEventListener()` won't work, it will minus multiple time as a loop. Use `addListenerForSingleValueEvent()` instead `addValueEventListener()`.

As the name says, this listener fits for single changes in the data at any location.

Answer (score 1):

I guess the problem is with dataSnapshot.getKey() in this line

```
DatabaseReference numMesasReference = mReference.child(dataSnapshot.getKey()).child("numeroMesas");
```

Here you getting the key for the whole list of Negocios, not for the specific child  replace it with `

```
postSnapshot.getKey()
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your `DatabaseReference` that you are using is wrong. You are missing a child. So in order to solve this problem, please use the following code:

```
mReference.child("Negocios").child(negociosId).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        int numeroMesas = (int) dataSnapshot.child("numeroMesas").getValue();
        if(nombre_lugar.equals(lugar.getUser_id())){
            mReference.child("Negocios").child(negociosId).child("numeroMesas").setValue(numeroMesas - 1);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
});
```

In which `negociosId` is the unique id generated by the `push()` method.

Hope it helps.

Comment: How can I get the unique id? I have multiple objects uploaded using push() method.

Comment: When you are using the `push()` method, is the moment in which you can get that unique key. You can achieve this using this line of code: `String negociosId = yourRef.getKey();`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm new to firebase and android. But If the above solutions doesn't work please do the following. I think the problem is that you didn't convert the value of numeroMesas to string. Sorry if there's anything wrong. 
Hope it helps.

```
mReference.child("Negocios").child(negociosId).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

        if(nombre_lugar.equals(lugar.getUser_id())){
            mReference.child("Negocios").child(negociosId).child("numeroMesas").setValue((Integer.parseInt(dataSnapshot.child("numeroMesas").getValue().toString())) - 1);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
});
```