# Firebase Updation of Single Item Using Android

Tags: android, firebase

I am trying to store in Firebase the class shown below

```
public class Riders {
String uberId;
String role;
double lat;
double lng;
String phone;
String request ;
```

Using the code below I have been able to store the data into firebase.

```
dbRef = fbDbase.getReference("Riders") ;

uberId = riders.getUberId();
phone = riders.getPhone();      
riders.setLat(uLatLng.latitude);
riders.setLng(uLatLng.longitude);
riders.setRequest("Active");


rowKey =dbRef.child(uberId).push().getKey();
dbRef.child(uberId).push().setValue(riders);
```

JSON export of data is given below        [Initial json with proper data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D4KWx.png)

```
I am facing a problem when I try to update the "Request" element value to Inactive.

1. 
String str = uberId + "/" + rowKey  ;
Map<String, Object> data = new HashMap<>();
data.put(str,"InActive");
dbRef.child(str).updateChildren(data);

The above code produces a structure as in the image [Incorrect Json ][1]
```

As you can observe -L7S7dZuZD7kZrS7kILu is the original key which has been completely modified  with only the Inactive value
left  behind. In addition to this a new node with a new key is being appended .

2. the code below creates a complete new node. For one Id I get two nodes with different rowkey values.

   ```
       dbRef.child(uberId).child(rowkey).child("Request").setValue("Inactive");
   ```

The question is how do we update a specific data item in firebase from android ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Update specific Values using Firebase for Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33315353/update-specific-values-using-firebase-for-android)

Comment: the data structure levels are different between the two datasets that's why that solution will not work here. I have /riders/id/pushid/child items. In the other soln it is /task/id/child items.

Answer (score 0):

I have modified my code for pushing in nodes

```
DatabaseReference newDbRef = dbRef.child(uberId).push();
newDbRef.setValue(riders);
rowKey =newDbRef.getKey();
```

My updating code looks like

```
String str = uberId + "/" + rowKey + "/" + "request" ;
Map<String, Object> data = new HashMap<String, Object>();
data.put(str,"InActive");
dbRef.child(str).updateChildren(data);
```

Now duplicate pushid's are not being created
But still updating  of request child item from "Active" to "Inactive" is not happening.As you can see from the attached image Request child node has a whole new branch after the updateChildren
[request child node now has a seperate branch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OV9h0.png)

Comment: I got it to work.  I made the following changes in the code              
   String str =  uberId + "/" + rowKey  ;    
    Map<String, Object> data = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    data.put("request","InActive");
    dbRef.child(str).updateChildren(data); Get the rowkey after the push. When using updateChildren method the parameter to dbref.child() should point to the parent of the child you want to update. Child item names are case sensitive ie Request differs from request