# Facing the problem from updating the data and delete data in android

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to learn the android and need your help!

**Problem 1:** 
I store my data with ".push()" . How do I update the data on the random number that I declared with ".push()".
**Once I update that only create new data but not a data update**

[image]

**Problem 2**
Once I delete the data will delete whole data but not only the specific data.

This is my **timetable.java**.

```
public class Timetable extends AppCompatActivity{

    //View
    RecyclerView timeTable;
    RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager;
    DatabaseReference counterRef,currentRef;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_ttable);
        timeTable = (RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.timeTable);
        timeTable.setHasFixedSize(true);
        layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        timeTable.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar)findViewById(R.id.toolBar);
        toolbar.setTitle("Time Table");
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        counterRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Time");
        currentRef = counterRef.child(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid());


        //online list here
        updateList();
    }

    private void updateList() {
        FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Time, ListTimeViewHolder> adapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Time, ListTimeViewHolder>(
                Time.class,
                R.layout.time_table,
                ListTimeViewHolder.class,
                currentRef
        ) {

            @Override
            protected void populateViewHolder(final ListTimeViewHolder viewHolder, final Time model, int position) {

                    viewHolder.txtEmail.setText("Time (" +model.getTime()+ ")");


                viewHolder.itemClickListenener1 = new ItemClickListenener1() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view, int position) {

                        showUpdateDeleteLog(model.getEmail(),model.getTime());

                        //alert dialog
//                        AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(Timetable.this).create();
//
//                            // Setting Dialog Title
//                            alertDialog.setTitle("Message");
//
//                            // Setting Dialog Message
//                            alertDialog.setMessage("Unable to click");
//
//                            alertDialog.setButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
//                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
//                                    // Write your code here to execute after dialog closed
//                                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "OK", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
//                                }
//                            });
//
//                            // Showing Alert Message
//                            alertDialog.show();
                        }

                    private void showUpdateDeleteLog(String email, String time) {
                        AlertDialog.Builder dialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(Timetable.this);
                        LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
                        final View dialogView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.update_dialog, null);
                        dialogBuilder.setView(dialogView);

                        final EditText editTextName = (EditText) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.editTextName);
                        final Button buttonUpdate = (Button) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.buttonUpdateArtist);
                        final Button buttonDelete = (Button) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.buttonDeleteArtist);

                        dialogBuilder.setTitle(email);
                        final AlertDialog b = dialogBuilder.create();
                        b.show();


                        buttonUpdate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(View view) {
                                String name = editTextName.getText().toString().trim();
                                if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(name)) {
                                    updateArtist(model.getEmail(),name);
                                    b.dismiss();
                                }
                            }
                        });


                        buttonDelete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(View view) {
                                deleteArtist(model.getEmail(),model.getTime());
                                b.dismiss();
                            }
                        });
                    }

                    private boolean deleteArtist(String email, String time) {
                        //getting the specified artist reference
                        DatabaseReference dR = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Time").child(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid());
                        //removing artist
                        dR.removeValue();
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Time is deleted", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        return true;
                    }

                    private boolean updateArtist(String email, String time) {
                        //getting the specified artist reference
                        DatabaseReference dR = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Time").child(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid());

                        //updating artist
                        Time artist = new Time(email,time);
                        dR.push().setValue(artist);
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Time is updated", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        return true;
                    }

                };
            }



        };
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        timeTable.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

}
```

Thanks for help! I'm newbie in Android need pro to help me up! Thanks guys and this platform!

Comment: not familiar with firebase, but have you read this ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33315353/update-specific-values-using-firebase-for-android

Comment: You need to get `id` of selected item and then use it in `deleteArtist` and `updateArtist` functions.

Comment: @ZwalPyaeKyaw yes, this is what i dont know how to get the id

Comment: @JohnJoe thanks , but see the person haven't solve his problem

Comment: @JasonLim when you `retrieve` the list from `firebase`, you can carry `id` and put it in your `object`. Then, get that `id` of the selected item.

Comment: @ZwalPyaeKyaw have any example to see? Thanks

Comment: [https://github.com/rozdoum/social-app-android](https://github.com/rozdoum/social-app-android) learn from it. It's a social app that looks like facebook. You can find your solution in app's comment feature section.

Comment: If you are confused about exploring the project. I can help you personally. You can PM me at zwalpyaekyaw.hml@gmail.com. I'll solve the project for you and explain details about firebase that you want to happen.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, why do you need to push() after Uid? As Uid is always unique, you can remove that to easily access the child node like below:

```
-Time
  -UID
    -email
    -time
```

> Problem 1: I store my data with ".push()" . How do I update the data on the random number that I declared with ".push()".

You need to get the reference of that particular node to update. For that, you can store the push Id along with email and time. Also, you don't need to push while updating.

```
private boolean updateArtist(String email, String time) {
                    //getting the specified artist reference
                    DatabaseReference dR = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Time").child(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid()).child(timeModel.getPushId());

                    //updating artist
                    Time artist = new Time(email,time);
                    dR.updateChildren(artist); // instead use updateChildren
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Time is updated", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    return true;
                }
```

> Once I delete the data will delete whole data but not only the specific data

Same goes for problem 2, you need that particular node to delete,

```
private boolean deleteArtist(String email, String time) {
                    //getting the specified artist reference
                    DatabaseReference dR = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Time").child(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid()).child(timeModel.getPushId());
                    //removing artist
                    dR.getRef().removeValue();
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Time is deleted", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    return true;
                }
```

Comment: hi bro, .child(timeModel.getPushId());  .... there shows cannot resolve symbol "timeModel" . Do you have any solution to solve this?

Comment: timeModel is just a random variable name for your model class "Time". You can replace that with your variable name that you have assigned for your POJO. I guess you are using "model".

Comment: hi there how to gt the pushid ? I didn't declared